Python con Pandas no se está leyendo todos los registros de un CSV un poco grande
ojalá puedan ayudarme. Al leer con Pandas un CSV un poco grande de 400 mb, no se está leyendo todos los registros.  El url del open data es: URL
Con pandas sólo consigo leer 1,189,096 registros pero el archivo tiene 1,216,582 incluida la cabecera. Las versiones de días anteriores de ese archivo sí se leían completas y sin problema, incluso sin tener que especificar el col_names, pero desde hoy daba el error
"pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 32 fields in line 417545, saw 44"   

por lo que tuve que especificar las columnas pero no lee todo el archivo y no me da mensajes de error.
El código que uso en python es:
col_names = ["N", "TIPO_SEGURO", "SEXO", "TIEMPO_EDAD", "EDAD", "ESTADO_CIVIL", "NIVEL_DE_INSTRUCCION", "ETNIA", "COD_UBIGEO_DOMICILIO", "PAIS_DOMICILIO", "DEPARTAMENTO_DOMICILIO", "PROVINCIA_DOMICILIO", "DISTRITO_DOMICILIO", "FECHA", "ANIO", "MES", "TIPO_LUGAR", "INSTITUCION", "MUERTE_VIOLENTA", "NECROPSIA", "DEBIDO_CAUSA_A", "CAUSA_A_CIEX", "DEBIDO_CAUSA_B", "CAUSA_B_CIEX", "DEBIDO_CAUSA_C", "CAUSA_C_CIEX", "DEBIDO_CAUSA_D", "CAUSA_D_CIEX", "DEBIDO_CAUSA_E", "CAUSA_E_CIEX", "DEBIDO_CAUSA_F", "CAUSA_F_CIEX"]
tipo_de_datos = {"N":'int64', "TIPO_SEGURO":'string', "SEXO":'string', "TIEMPO_EDAD":'string', "EDAD":'string', "ESTADO_CIVIL":'string', "NIVEL_DE_INSTRUCCION":'string', "ETNIA":'string', "COD_UBIGEO_DOMICILIO":'string', "PAIS_DOMICILIO":'string', "DEPARTAMENTO_DOMICILIO":'string', "PROVINCIA_DOMICILIO":'string', "DISTRITO_DOMICILIO":'string', "FECHA":'string', "ANIO":'int64', "MES":'int64', "TIPO_LUGAR":'string', "INSTITUCION":'string', "MUERTE_VIOLENTA":'string', "NECROPSIA":'string', "DEBIDO_CAUSA_A":'string', "CAUSA_A_CIEX":'string', "DEBIDO_CAUSA_B":'string', "CAUSA_B_CIEX":'string', "DEBIDO_CAUSA_C":'string', "CAUSA_C_CIEX":'string', "DEBIDO_CAUSA_D":'string', "CAUSA_D_CIEX":'string', "DEBIDO_CAUSA_E":'string', "CAUSA_E_CIEX":'string', "DEBIDO_CAUSA_F":'string', "CAUSA_F_CIEX":'string'}
df = pd.read_csv(archivo_csv, names=col_names, sep=",", low_memory=False,skiprows=1 ,dtype= tipo_de_datos)
df9 = df.groupby(['ANIO']).N.count()
print(df9)
print(df.shape[0]) # Para saber cuantos registros ha cargado el pandas

Por favor, si me pueden ayudar porque se me acaban las ideas, ya usé eliminar el  low_memory, eliminar el dtype y no cambia el resultado. Les agradezco de antemano.

La URL que publicas no apunta a ningun archivo y además pide login. ¿Donde podemos mirar esos datos?

También podrías publicar una versión recortada del archivo, unos 10 registros antes y 10 registros después de la línea señalada en el error.

El problema es del CSV y su mal uso de las comillas dobles... Las comillas dobles se usan generalmente como quotechar por defecto, carácter usado para delimitar campos o caracteres especiales (delimitador, terminadores de linea o el propio quotechar) que no deben interpretarse como tales sino como parte de los datos.
Por ejemplo, en:
Nombre,Edad
"García, José", 47
"María, Cobos", 29

las comillas dobles acotan la primera columna indicándole al parser que la coma que separa el apellido y el nombre no es un separador, sino parte de los datos de la primera columna.
En tu csv tenemos un problema con esto, en la línea por la que el parser se queja tenemos:
...,NO SE REALIZÓ NECROPSIA,"DIABETES MELLITUS NO ESPECIFI,E147,...
                            ^
                            ^
                            Comillas no cerradas

Como por defecto se usan las comillas dobles como quotechar y quoting es por defecto csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL (se delimitan con comillas los campos que contienen alguno de los caracteres especiales mencionados arriba), cuando el parser llega a las comillas de apertura procede a ignorar las comas (separador) hasta que se encuentra con comillas de cierre, ignorando por el camino finales de linea y demás caracteres especiales. Ignorar separadores y saltos de linea, que lo son realmente, obviamente causa filas con menos columnas de las esperadas, filas enteras perdidas incluidas en un solo campo, que se encuentre con el final del archivo a mitad del parseado de una fila, etc.
El archivo es muy largo y tienes más de 3000 filas con comillas no emparejadas...
Todos los errores parecen estar en los campos de las columnas DEBIDO_CAUSA_<X> y parecen ser el resultado de truncar el contenido de cadenas largas, por ejemplo en la linea mencionada, originalmente podría ser:
...,NO SE REALIZÓ NECROPSIA,"DIABETES MELLITUS NO ESPECIFICADA",E147,...

pero al truncarla se han comido también las comillas de cierre...
Dado que no hay un verdadero estándar para CSV (lo mas cercano es RFC 4180) no se puede decir que sea incorrecto, pero desde luego yo no me sentiría orgulloso de ese CSV si fuera mio... Lo ideal sería que se corrigiera desde el origen, o no deberían haberse truncado los datos, o deberían haberse truncado sin eliminar también las comillas de cierre finales o debería al menos especificarse la estrategia de quoting y quotechar que se usa.
Dado que parece que no hay separadores (comas) ni finales de linea en los datos de estos campos una opción algo bruta seŕia desactivar el acotado o especificar como  quotechar un carácter que no exista en el documento:
df = pd.read_csv("SINADEF_DATOS_ABIERTOS.csv", sep=",", quoting=3, low_memory=False)



>>> df.info(verbose=False)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1216581 entries, 0 to 1216580
Columns: 32 entries, N to CAUSA_F_CIEX
dtypes: int64(3), object(29)
memory usage: 297.0+ MB


Esto hará que las comillas se interpreten como un carácter más, por ejemplo, la fila problemática de tu error en el dataframe queda:

>>> df.iloc[417543]
N                                                 417544
TIPO_SEGURO                                          SIS
SEXO                                            FEMENINO
TIEMPO_EDAD                                         AÑOS
EDAD                                                  53
ESTADO_CIVIL                                     SOLTERO
NIVEL_DE_INSTRUCCION               SECUNDARIA INCOMPLETA
ETNIA                                            MESTIZO
COD_UBIGEO_DOMICILIO                  92-33-09-02-01-000
PAIS_DOMICILIO                                      PERU
DEPARTAMENTO_DOMICILIO                           HUANUCO
PROVINCIA_DOMICILIO                                 AMBO
DISTRITO_DOMICILIO                                  AMBO
FECHA                                         2023-01-31
ANIO                                                2023
MES                                                    1
TIPO_LUGAR                                          EESS
INSTITUCION                            GOBIERNO REGIONAL
MUERTE_VIOLENTA                             SIN REGISTRO
NECROPSIA                        NO SE REALIZÓ NECROPSIA
DEBIDO_CAUSA_A            "DIABETES MELLITUS NO ESPECIFI
CAUSA_A_CIEX                                        E147
DEBIDO_CAUSA_B                              SIN REGISTRO
CAUSA_B_CIEX                                SIN REGISTRO
DEBIDO_CAUSA_C                              SIN REGISTRO
CAUSA_C_CIEX                                SIN REGISTRO
DEBIDO_CAUSA_D                              SIN REGISTRO
CAUSA_D_CIEX                                SIN REGISTRO
DEBIDO_CAUSA_E                              SIN REGISTRO
CAUSA_E_CIEX                                SIN REGISTRO
DEBIDO_CAUSA_F                              SIN REGISTRO
CAUSA_F_CIEX                                SIN REGISTRO
Name: 417543, dtype: object


El problema es que si las dobles comillas si se usan en ese CSV como quotechar y eventualmente en el futuro si hay un carácter que debería ser delimitado, tendremos problemas, por ejemplo si tenemos algo como:
...,NO SE REALIZÓ NECROPSIA,"DIABETES MELLITUS, NO ESPECIFI,E147,...

Otra opción es intentar arreglar los campos que no tienen comillas de cierre antes de parsear el documento, se puede conseguir algo decente usando regex por ejemplo.

Gracias @FJSevilla. Además de la solución especificando como quoting un caracter alterno, me funcionó también leer el archivo a bajo nivel eliminando las comillas dobles. Con eso, pandas pudo leer todos los registros sin tener que especificar los col_names.  Sugiero que Pandas o Python informen que se han saltado algunos registros al usar el parámetro names= col_names, para que los desarrolladores podamos tener una alerta y verificar los registros perdidos, en este caso veo que cada registro tiene un retorno de carro  (CR) y un salto de línea (LF).
